# Get 2D elements from 3D numpy array, corresponding to 2D indices

Tags: numpy, numpy-indexing

I have a 3D array that could be interpreted as a 2D matrix of positions, where each position is a 2D array of coordinates `[x,y]`.

I then have a list of 2D indices, each one indicating a position in the matrix in terms of [row, column].
I would like to obtain the positions from the matrix corresponding to all these indices.

What I am doing is:

```
import numpy as np

input_matrix = np.array(
    [[[0.0, 1.5], [3.0, 3.0]], [[7.0, 5.2], [6.0, 7.0]]]
)

indices = np.array([[1, 0], [1, 1]])

selected_elements = np.array([input_matrix[tuple(idx)] for idx in indices])
```

So for example the 2D element corresponding to the 2D index `[1, 0]` would be `[7.0, 5.2]` and so on.

My code works, but I was wondering if there is a better and way, for example using numpy entirely (e.g. without having to use list comprehension in the case of multiple 2D indices).

I tried to use the numpy `take` but it does not seem to produce the wanted results.

Comment: So just `input_matrix[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
input_matrix[tuple(indices.T)]
```

Or, as suggested in comments:

```
input_matrix[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]]
```

Output:

```
array([[7. , 5.2],
       [6. , 7. ]])
```